# How do I go back to the old tab switcher on Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser-tabs

I don't know when this happened but in the latest version of Google Chrome for Android, I can't swipe down from the 'open tabs' button to get the card UI of all open tabs and switch to or close the tab I want.

What I see now when I swipe down from the 'open tabs' button is an ugly list containing a list of all open tabs and it always starts at the top so I have scroll all the way down to close the most recently opened tab.

Does anyone know how to go back to the way it was? Maybe there's an experimental flag I could enable or disable?

Comment: Found the answer: Disable 'Simplified view for open tabs' in Chrome settings -> Accessibility. Source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/bl1emv/accessibility_tab_switcher_showing_even_if_its/emvsfzi)